# I want to send only one email using SMTP (gmail) with in 100 to 200 milli seconds?

Tags: performance, email

Below java code is taking 2 seconds.

```
 Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
 store.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "******@gmail.com", "*******");
 Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
 t.connect("******@gmail.com", "******");
 t.sendMessage(replyMessage,replyMessage.getAllRecipients());
```

Comment: You have zero control over how long `smtp.gmail.com` will take.  It makes no sense to have a performance metric like that on a protocol specifically designed for store and forward.  In short your cannot do it.

Comment: Mailing systems are pretty slow and clearly not designed with low latency in mind. They are rather designed to scale with the large amount of mail and users, resulting in higher latency (eg. buffering, compression, etc.). Not to mention they are also designed to be relatively safe too.